# Calling member function on non existing object works correctly, c++

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, reinterpret-cast

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class someClass
{
public:
    someClass(){ cout<<"someClass"<<endl; }
    void g() const { cout<<"g()"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    void* memory = new void*[5*(sizeof(someClass)/sizeof(char))];
    someClass *someClassArray = reinterpret_cast<someClass*>(memory);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        someClassArray[i].g();
    }       
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
g()
g()
g()
g()
g()
```

Which means that no constructor was called. But in array someClassArray are onjects of someClass type and I am allowed to call a g() function and get a proper output.

Why this program is executet correctly, while no object of type someClass is consructed?

Comment: Why are you surprised it executes correctly? This is undefined behavior, working correctly is certainly an option. Implementation wise, it's just a function call, so it's _probable_ that it'll work correctly. Just don't rely on it, ever.

Comment: yeh, essentially you just got lucky. Here's a summary of the reinterpret_cast rules. See the section called "type aliasing": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When member function g() is called the compiler simply pass to it as the first argument the pointer to the object (that is to an element of the allocated array of type void * that you interpret as someClass *). The function does not use this pointer to access any data member of the class. In fact for this simple class there is nothing that the constructor has to construct. The class has no data members. So there is no problem to call the function.

Comment: It is (normally benign) UB. Perhaps emphasize that the observed handling is not guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

`someClass` is a class with no state.
 It is not surprising that g() is not handled like a vtable pointer, but rather a regular function.

What you are doing here is undefined behaviour pandering to intuition, reinterpret_cast, rather than specs.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation has been done for the someClass objects, with you call of `new`. However, as the call is `new void` and not `new someClass`, it hasn't called someClass constructor.

The call of `g()` works because `this` pointer has been allocated. Only constructor operations will never be executed.